# Joining files from multiple directories bash

Tags: bash, loops

I have multiple restarts of some of my simulations. The number of restarts varies from case to case. For post processing, I have to combine the output from all these restarts into single files that I can analyze. My naming convention for the runs/restarts is simple. For example for run101, my restarts would be named run101r1, run101r2 etc.

I came up with this bash script:

```
vars=(a b c d e f)
runname=$1
for i in ${vars[*]}; do
echo 'Combining movies for ' $i
cat $runname/staging/movie.$i.000 $runname\r1/staging/movie.$i.001 > ./$i
done
```

The only problem is that, given different numbers of restarts for different runs, I currently manually change the second last line for each run. Is there a way to make the second last line into a loop as well so that I can simply invoke the script as:

```
>combine_movies.sh run101 n
```

where n is the number of restarts?

Answer (score 0):

After some experimentation, I was able to create a string and evaluate that string. Here is the final script:

```
vars=(a b c d e f)
for i in ${vars[*]}; do
  a="cat $1/staging/movie.$i.000 "
   for j in $(seq 1 $2); do
     a="$a $1r$j/staging/movie.$i.00$j "
   done
  a="$a > ./$i"
  echo $a
  eval $a
done
```

Can this be cleaned up even more? Maybe, made a bit more general and fool-proof?